# NVD3 and RCharts in Shiny

Tags: r, nvd3.js, rcharts

I have very simple question but there seems to be problem in finding the answer,

I know when using `ggplot` within `shiny` one can use `aes_string()` to change value through input for columns.
So when i change selectinput for Test1,Test2 or Test3, I can get values on a barplot.

Data

```
Color   Test1   Test2   Test3

Black    23      43      56 

Blue     32      34      45

Yellow   33      93      35
```

Code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


    output$column <- renderPlot({

        n1<-nPlot(hrs_0to1 ~ TicketType, data=sum1, type="multiBarChart",height=600,width=1000)
        n1$chart(reduceXTicks=FALSE)
        n1$xAxis(staggerLabels=TRUE)
        print(n1)


  })

})
```

The above doesnt work because, I think i cannot use input in such a way.

Please suggest a method to resolve this.

**UPDATE**

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


shinyUI(fluidPage(

    column(12,offset=5,
           titlePanel("Template Type by Hours")),
    br(),
    h6(textOutput("text1")),

    fluidRow(

        column(4,offset=0,
               wellPanel(
                   selectInput("var","Hours",
                               choices = colnames(sum1),selected ="hrs_0to1")))),

    column(12,offset=0,
           plotOutput("column", height=500,width=1000)
    ),

    column(12,
           dataTableOutput("table1")
    )

))
```

**server.R**

```
library(devtools)
library(rCharts)
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$column <- renderChart2({

        n1<-nPlot(x="TicketType",y= input$var, data=sum1, type="multiBarChart")
        n1$chart(reduceXTicks=FALSE)
        n1$xAxis(staggerLabels=TRUE)
        print(n1)

        })

})
```

**Data Structure**

```
> str(sum1)
'data.frame':   37 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Ttype            : Factor w/ 4 levels "Complaint","Others",..: 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 4 2 3 ...
 $ TicketType       : Factor w/ 37 levels "Address change",..: 4 15 2 36 22 1 12 25 18 21 ...
 $ hrs_0to1         : num  24.95 24.13 21.39 7.05 5.25 ...
 $ hrs_1to6         : num  9.3 24.63 32.03 3.49 8.11 ...
 $ hrs_6to12        : num  19.5 15.13 23.68 2.88 6.96 ...
 $ hrs_12to24       : num  6.02 11.35 18.07 3.15 6.12 ...
 $ hrs_24to48       : num  1.43 7.94 7.41 2.45 5.01 1.32 2.71 0.23 0 2.03 ...
 $ hrs_48to96       : num  0.27 6.29 3.31 1.76 3.56 0.76 2.16 0.12 0 1.67 ...
 $ Call_Before_Order: int  0 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Data Example

```
> dput(head(sum1, 20))
structure(list(TicketType = structure(c(1L, 12L, 23L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
13L), .Label = c("Dummy-1", "Dummy-10", "Dummy-11", "Dummy-12", 
"Dummy-13", "Dummy-14", "Dummy-15", "Dummy-16", "Dummy-17", "Dummy-18", 
"Dummy-19", "Dummy-2", "Dummy-20", "Dummy-21", "Dummy-22", "Dummy-23", 
"Dummy-24", "Dummy-25", "Dummy-26", "Dummy-27", "Dummy-28", "Dummy-29", 
"Dummy-3", "Dummy-30", "Dummy-31", "Dummy-32", "Dummy-33", "Dummy-34", 
"Dummy-35", "Dummy-36", "Dummy-37", "Dummy-4", "Dummy-5", "Dummy-6", 
"Dummy-7", "Dummy-8", "Dummy-9"), class = "factor"), hrs_0to1 = c(4.04, 
21.39, 0.14, 24.95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 3.95, 0, 0, 24.13, 
0.23, 0, 2.05, 0, 1.28), hrs_1to6 = c(3.08, 32.03, 0.18, 9.3, 
0, 0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.61, 0.06, 0, 24.63, 4.68, 0, 0.18, 
0, 2.25), hrs_6to12 = c(3.06, 23.68, 0.28, 19.5, 0.09, 0.09, 
0, 0.19, 0, 0.37, 0, 5.94, 1.3, 0, 15.13, 10.31, 0, 0.46, 0, 
2.23), hrs_12to24 = c(2.5, 18.07, 0.09, 6.02, 0.05, 0.32, 0, 
0.46, 0, 1.71, 0, 4.17, 10.15, 0.09, 11.35, 13.16, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 
3.43), hrs_24to48 = c(1.32, 7.41, 0.11, 1.43, 0.08, 0.64, 0.08, 
1.99, 0, 4.74, 0.08, 2.71, 12.83, 0.08, 7.94, 12.68, 0, 0, 0, 
6.06), hrs_48to96 = c(0.76, 3.31, 0.24, 0.27, 0, 2.25, 0.27, 
1.46, 0.09, 5.38, 0.06, 2.16, 10, 0.09, 6.29, 12.25, 0.06, 0, 
0, 6.84), hrs_above96 = c(0, 1.97, 0, 0, 0, 3.95, 0.66, 3.29, 
0, 3.29, 0, 0.66, 8.55, 0, 0.66, 14.47, 0, 0, 0, 11.84)), .Names = c("TicketType", 
"hrs_0to1", "hrs_1to6", "hrs_6to12", "hrs_12to24", "hrs_24to48", 
"hrs_48to96", "hrs_above96"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks David for the formatting!

Comment: NVD3 supports non formula inputs too. So you can do `nPlot(x = "TicketType", y = "hrs_0to1", ...)` and include an `input` variable for use with Shiny.

Comment: @Ramnath `n1<-nPlot(x="TicketType",y= input$var, data=sum1, type="multiBarChart",height=600,width=1000)
n1$chart(reduceXTicks=FALSE)
n1$xAxis(staggerLabels=TRUE)
print(n1)` I am trying something like this my Y-axis is my variable. but this way it doesn't work

Comment: You are using `renderPlot`. You need to use `renderChart2`, which is needed to render `rCharts` plots.

Comment: `library(devtools)
library(rCharts)
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$column <- renderChart2({

        n1<-nPlot(x="TicketType",y= input$var, data=sum1,    type="multiBarChart")
        n1$chart(reduceXTicks=FALSE)
        n1$xAxis(staggerLabels=TRUE)
        print(n1)

  })

})` Its not working, I am a learner with Rcharts and Shiny but I have the code working since I don't see an error, still I dont see the Chart..

Comment: I have included my ui.R and server.R code for better understanding.

Comment: Without your data `sum1` it is hard to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: @Ramnath, I have added the Structure of my data, hope this will help to solve this...

Comment: That doesn't help much. Can you paste the contents of `dput(head(sum1, 20))` so that I have a sample of the dataset to work with?

Comment: I have added the data using the above code.